# custom hooks before a comment is updated/edited in the database

Tags: comments, hooks, wpdb

Is it possible to create a custom hook if a comment is updated/edited in the database?

I want a hook, something like this:

```
add_action('before_edit_comment', 'myfunction');
function myfunction($comment_id, $comment_object){
 // do something
}
```

Actually, I want to keep the history if a user edits/updates a comment like Facebook. Please give me your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Updating an existing comment in the database is done by the function [`wp_update_comment`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_comment/). As you can see, there is one hook, `edit_comment`, which you can use to trigger an action when a comment is updated.

However, this hook fires after the comment has been updated. If you want to store the older version of the comment the hook is no use. Also, there is no obvious way to store older versions op the comment. You would have to modify the datastructure, for instance by creating an [additional comment metadata](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_comment_meta/) field.

You could then hook into the `comment_save_pre` filter in `wp_update_comment` to store the old content in that metafield.

Answer (score 1):

There are 6 hooks that can be used with comment forms if you are logged in - to my knowledge. These are

- comment_form
- comment_form_before
- comment_form_after
- comment_form_top
- comment_form_before_fields
- comment_form_after_fields

If the user is not logged in, I am aware of only 4 available hooks:

- comment_form
- comment_form_before
- comment_form_after
- comment_form_top

Which to use depends on what you want to do. If you want to perform some action only if the content is updated, then you should recover the content using the comment_form_before hook and then perform your action using the comment_form_after hook only if this content changes when the form is submitted.